# How do I add Sprite based on score?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So far, I almost finished my game. I have a ball that falls due to gravity and the person taps it to make it bounce. Every time the sprite is tapped, +1 is added to the score. There are 3 balls in total that show up when the view loads.I want each ball to show up at a certain point mark(one ball shows up when the person reaches 10 points, another when the player reaches 20).

I tried putting this in `update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)`, but I end up with this:

[image]

(This is the secondball coming in at 10 points.)

Seems like there are an infinite number of balls until the person gets to 21 points which stops the never-ending cascade. If you tap the cascade though, it does pick a ball and makes it jump out which is sorta what I wanted.

This is **GameScene.swift** (excluding the `update(CFTimeInterval)` function)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
var ball: Ball!
var secondball: Ball!


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 //=======Ball 1=======//
    let ball = Ball()

    ball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:440)

    addChild(ball)



    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0


    //======Ball 2======//
    let secondball = Ball()
    secondball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX * 1.65, y: 440)
    addChild(secondball)



    secondball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
    secondball.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    secondball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    secondball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    secondball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    secondball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    secondball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    secondball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0
}

class Ball: SKSpriteNode {



    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ball")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        userInteractionEnabled = true

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let scene = self.scene as! GameScene
        scene.score += 1

        physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 100)
        physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 900))



    }

}

 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


    if (score >= 10){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "orangebackground")
    }


    if (score >= 20){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "yellowbackground")
    }


    if (score >= 30) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "greenbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 40){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bluebackground")
    }
    if (score >= 50){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "darkbluebackground")
    }
    if (score >= 60){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "purplebackground")
    }
    if (score >= 70){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "brownbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 80) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "maroonbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 90){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tanbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 100){
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "pinkbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 125) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bronzebackground")
    }
    if (score >= 150) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "silverbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 175) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "goldbackground")
    }
    if (score >= 200) {
        self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "elitebackground")

    }




  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The update method is called faster then the increased score. Therefore in every call of the update method a new ball is added.

Try something like this:

Move this line of code outside of the update method to make a global variable which has one ball instance:

```
let secondball = Ball()
```

Inside of update:

```
 if (score == 10) && secondball.parent == nil {
```

Comment: The game crashes when performing this.

Comment: check update. I put the code back to what I originally had so that I can get the actual simulator to work. Both balls are present immediately when the view loads.

Answer (score 0):

You have choosed to control the touches part to the `Ball` class, this is possible but not convenient.

First of all give a name to your balls during the creation:

```
ball.name = "ball1"
self.addChild(ball)
...
secondball.name = "ball2"
secondball.alpha = 0.0 // hide your secondBall at start
self.addChild(secondball)
```

Then , move the `touchesBegan` from your `Ball` class, to your `GameScene`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            switch name {
            case "ball1": // if you're touching ball1
                self.score += 1
                ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 100)
                ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 900))
                if score == 10 {
                    ball.removeFromParent()
                    // or make some animation like:
                    //let fadeOut=SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.0)
                    //ball.runAction(fadeOut,completion: {
                    //  self.ball.removeFromParent()
                    //})
                    secondball.alpha = 1
                    // or make some animation like:
                    //let fadeIn=SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5)
                    //secondball.runAction(fadeIn,completion: {
                    //    self.secondball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
                    //})
                    secondball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
                }
            case "ball2": // if you're touching ball2
                self.score += 1
                secondball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 100) // here you can decrease parameters to more difficult
                secondball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 900))
                if score == 20 {
                   // do the same thing maked for ball to show other ball
                }
            case "ball3": // if you're touching ball3
                self.score += 1
                secondball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 100) // here you can decrease parameters to more difficult
                secondball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 900))               
                if score == 21 {
                   // do other stuff here
                }
            default: 
               break 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. It doesn't add +1 to the score so I can't see if the rest of the code works with the other balls fading in.

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint to "switch name" and check why your score dont increase his value

Comment: I'm not sure why. I added a breakpoint to `switch name {` in `case ball1`. After tapping the ball, the simulation still keeps going.

Comment: Have you forgot to add names to the nodes? Was the first node selected and executed after the switch case?

Comment: I did put the names on each node. If I delete the `touchesbegan` inside the `ball` class, then it does not add a point. If I don't delete it and just add the code you gave me, then It does add the points, but does not show the second and third balls when it reaches 10 and 20 points.